# NSIS - section dependency .onSelChange

Tags: dependencies, nsis

I need a little help or advise how to force SEC033 & SEC085 section's to work together in this way:
1. when SEC033 is selected, SEC085 should be selected & when SEC033 is unselected, SEC085 should be unselected to
2. when SEC085 is selected, SEC033 should be selected & when SEC085 is unselected, SEC033 should be unselected to

My nsis section structure:

```
SectionGroup "$(SEC03)" SEC03    

    Section "Product 1" SEC031
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

    Section "Product 3" SEC033
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

    Section "Product 6" SEC036
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

SectionGroupEnd    

SectionGroup "$(SEC08)" SEC08    

    Section "Product 2" SEC082
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

    Section "Product 5" SEC085
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

    Section "Product 8" SEC088
        SectionIn 1 2
    SectionEnd    

SectionGroupEnd
```

I have no idea how to do that, unfortunately I'm not familiar with all this `SectionGetFlags`/`SectionSetFlags`

I try to use this:

```
SectionGetFlags ${SEC033} $0
SectionSetFlags ${SEC085} $0
```

& for SEC033 works great

but when I add

```
SectionGetFlags ${SEC085} $0
SectionSetFlags ${SEC033} $0
```

SEC085 wont work at all, I understand that this is exactly the same but in opposite way & probably this is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it....:/

Comment: Your example entirely leaves out the part where you make use of SectionSetFlags. Also, examples should be kept as minimal as possible, so there's no need to post that many sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section flags stores more than just the checked state, it also stores group, bold and read-only flags so you should not use `SectionSetFlags` to set the state to just 0 or 1. Sections.nsh contains defines for each bit and it also contains helper macros you can use to manipulate sections. If you manually want to see if a section is checked (selected) you must use a bit test:

```
SectionGetFlags ${SEC033} $4
IntOp $4 $4 & ${SF_SELECTED}
```

LogicLib.nsh contains macros that lets you check sections in a ${If} statement:

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function .onSelChange
${If} $6 == "1" ; Use $6 here like you did in your answer
    StrCpy $6 0
    ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC033}
    ${OrIf} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC085}
        !insertmacro SelectSection ${SEC033}
        !insertmacro SelectSection ${SEC085}
    ${EndIf}
${Else}
    StrCpy $6 1
    ${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC033}
    ${OrIfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC085}
        !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SEC033}
        !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SEC085}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks definitely much more elegant, this is exacly what I'm looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have create a solution, maybe someone will need it also:)

```
SectionGetFlags ${SEC033} $4
SectionGetFlags ${SEC085} $8
StrCpy $2 "$4$8"
${If} $6 == "1"
  ${If} $2 == "01"
    SectionSetFlags ${SEC033} 1
    StrCpy $6 "0"
  ${Else}
    ${If} $2 == "10"
      SectionSetFlags ${SEC085} 1
      StrCpy $6 "0"
    ${Else}
    ${EndIf}
  ${EndIf}
${Else}
  ${If} $2 == "10"
    SectionSetFlags ${SEC033} 0
    StrCpy $6 "1"
  ${Else}
    ${If} $2 == "01"
      SectionSetFlags ${SEC085} 0
      StrCpy $6 "1"
    ${Else}
    ${EndIf}
  ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use SectionSetFlags like that!